# Shell Custom Renderer reset color set by TabBarUnselectedColor

Tags: c#, .net-maui, custom-renderer, .net-maui.shell

I have a .Net MAUI app that uses Shell TabBar:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="{StaticResource IconHome}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Coverage&#10;Calculator" Icon="{StaticResource IconCalculator}" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate calculator:CoverageCalculatorPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Distributor&#10;Locator" Icon="{StaticResource IconLocator}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate locator:DistributorsLocatorPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Scan&#10;QR Code" Icon="{StaticResource IconQrScanner}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate qrScanner:QrScannerPage}" />
    </Tab>        
    <Tab Title="More" Icon="{StaticResource IconMore}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate more:MoreFeaturesPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

The icon color is set in Styles.xaml like this:

```
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LaticreteColor}, Dark={StaticResource LaticreteColor}}" />
```

Here is how the TabBar looks:

[image]

As my tabs needed more than one line of text, I applied a custom renderer for Android:

```
internal class LaticreteShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public LaticreteShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new LaticreteTabLayout();
    }
    public class LaticreteTabLayout : Java.Lang.Object, IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            bottomView.SetMinimumHeight(180);

            var bottomNavView = bottomView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;

            for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavView.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var item = bottomNavView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);
                TextView smallTextView = (TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0);
                TextView largeTextView = (TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1);
                smallTextView.SetLines(2);
                largeTextView.SetLines(2);
            }
        }
```

This resets the tab's color:

[image]

I found that I can change the text color in the custom renderer like this:

```
                    smallTextView.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Brown);
                largeTextView.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Brown);
```

But I still don't know how to set the icon color, and how I can refer to my custom color set in App.xaml or Colors.xaml.

Why is TabBarUnselectedColor reset, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached property `TabBarUnselectedColor` that you set is not applied because you have overrode the method responsible on doing so `SetAppearance()`.

This can be fixed by simply calling that method from the base class at the begining like below:

```
public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
{
    base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
    bottomView.SetMinimumHeight(180);
    ...
 }
```

#### Edit (full code)

> no suitable method found to override"

```
internal class LaticreteShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public LaticreteShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new LaticreteTabLayout(this, shellItem);
    }
}

    public class LaticreteTabLayout : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {

    public LaticreteTabLayout (IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem) : base(shellContext, shellItem)
    {
    }
        public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);

            bottomView.SetMinimumHeight(180);

            var bottomNavView = bottomView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;

            for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavView.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var item = bottomNavView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);
                TextView smallTextView = (TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0);
                TextView largeTextView = (TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1);
                smallTextView.SetLines(2);
                largeTextView.SetLines(2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this line gives an error:
'Object' does not contain a definition for 'SetAppearance'

Comment: my bad i forgot the keyword `override` in the method signature, it might be the reason, strange that you don't have it in the code you posted

Comment: no, it is my bad. I did not provide the full code. I added it to my question. Currently, I get "'LaticreteShellRenderer.LaticreteTabLayout.SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView, IShellAppearanceElement)': no suitable method found to override"

Comment: please check my edit