# How to center title text of TabBar Tab?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-maui, custom-renderer, .net-maui.shell

This is a follow-up question, I am using the custom renderer in [Shell Custom Renderer reset color set by TabBarUnselectedColor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73530155/5228202)

In my .Net MAUI app, I use a `TabBar` in `AppShell`:

```
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="{StaticResource IconHome}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Coverage&#10;Calculator" Icon="{StaticResource IconCalculator}" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate calculator:CoverageCalculatorPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Distributor&#10;Locator" Icon="{StaticResource IconLocator}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate locator:DistributorsLocatorPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Scan&#10;QR Code" Icon="{StaticResource IconQrScanner}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate qrScanner:QrScannerPage}" />
        </Tab>        
        <Tab Title="More" Icon="{StaticResource IconMore}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate more:MoreFeaturesPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

The Titles of the Tabs are left aligned. Can they be centred?

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You are talking about ShellContent's Title (not included in your code) not Tab's Title? because Tab's Title is centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the alignment of the `TextView` :

```
using TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment;
smallTextView.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I actually meant Titles of the TabBar tabs. I added a picture to my question. You said the Title should be already centered, but perhaps it looks like this because the Title has two lines separated by a newline? If so, is there a way to do something to make it look centered?

Comment: it is better clear now with the picture, never mind my previous comment i was thinking about something else

Comment: Thanks, that works! But could you tell how this can be done for iOS?

Comment: not sure but probably using [textalignment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618618-textalignment) - [possible values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextalignment)